# Empty Input After AJAX Post Submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I want to empty OR clear input field after the comment has been submitted through jQuery AJAX post submit. Here is jQuery code I am using;

```
$(".textbox2").on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var message = $("#message").val(),
            privateid = $("#private");

        if (message == '') {
            alert("Message is missing!!");
            return;
        }

        if (privateid.is(':checked')) {
            var privateidVal = privateid.val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: "message=" +
                encodeURIComponent(message) +
                "&private=" +
                encodeURIComponent(privateidVal) +
                "&action=addcomment",
            success: function (data) {
                showComment();
                document.getElementById('message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('message').focus();
                document.getElementById('private').checked = '';

                if (data.error) {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

### INPUT FIELD:

`<input type="text" class="textbox2" size="90" maxlength="200" name="message" id="message" autocomplete="off" style="width: 90%;">`

The issue is, it cleared in Chrome but not in Safari and FirefOx browsers. What could be the reason? Please help!

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple elements with id "message"?

Comment: Not on the same page. I just have the mentioned Input Field on that page.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code?

Comment: Take a look at Firebug in FireFox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking fine to me., Try to use an updated jQuery Library, I think you're using an outdated library which is missing some required functions.

Comment: Yeah, I know and I have already solved this issue, however thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery

Instead of this

```
document.getElementById( 'message' ).value = '';
```

Try this...

```
$("#message").val("");
```

Comment: check with firebug are there any errors on the page..
And what is on your showComment(); function.

Comment: Show comment function is this:

` function showComment(){
   $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"shout.php",
    data:"action=showcomment",
    success:function(data){
    $("#comment").html(data);
    }
   });`

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting to the success function from the ajax call.

Comment: just commnt that showComment(); and check with an alert to see its working without showing the comment by using the showComment()

Comment: After commenting out showCommen(); the post does submitted but doesn't cleared the field.